# Caliburn Micro: Best approach for this app

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am new to WPF and Caliburn Micro and need some advice on how to organize my app.

The app is a configurations editor for a data mining framework. In the app, there will be one main window with a grid and a tree view in a left column and different settings editors in a right column. Which particular editor that is shown on the right depends on what item is selected in the tree view. Each editor consist of several controls (in one case up to about 200).

When switching between editors, i think the previous editor should be hidden/deactivated instead of closed to improve switching speed.

What i am wondering now is what is the best way to organize this app and how i switch between the editors?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a ViewModel first approach, have you checked out ISceens and the Screen implementation? The current Caliburn.Micro download contains a demo project with a screen coordinator implementation (SimpleMDI)

You can use the Activate/Deactivate functionality in the main viewmodel to handle switching between the 'properties' views.

The main viewmodel should derive from the caliburn provided implementation of `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive` where T should be IScreen. This allows your main view model to only activate one screen at a time.

Basically if you bind the 'selected item' to a property in the main viewmodel, you can watch for property changed notifications (using NotifyOfPropertyChange) and then use some sort of routine to decide which view to swtich to.

Caliburn will keep the views cached (use GetChildren on your Conductor) so you can switch between them - preserving performance.

I use something like this to dynamically instantiate my controls based on the database and available libs (note that my example is a bit confusing as CurrentView is actually a custom type and isn't really a view - it's just a database object which describes the control that has been selected.. I should probably change it!)

```
public MainPageViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    #region Property Changed handler

    public override void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        base.NotifyOfPropertyChange(propertyName);

        // A property changed, update the views if it's the CurrentView property
        UpdateViews(propertyName);
    }

    #endregion

    private void UpdateViews(string propertyName)
    {
        // If the selected item in my list changes, it's bound to CurrentView and contains
        // the fully qualified typename of the ViewModel that the items 'screen' should use
        if (propertyName == "CurrentView")
        {
            // If the selected item changes we need to load the control or retrieve it from the
            // control cache, making sure to update the cache and the active view dictionary
            try
            {                    
                var controlType = Type.GetType(CurrentView.QualifiedTypeName, true);

                // Check to see if the view is already loaded
                var view = GetChildren().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == controlType);

                // If it is, just activate it
                if (view != null)
                {
                    ActivateItem(view);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise it's not loaded, load it and activate it
                    view = (IScreen)Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
                    ActivateItem(view);

                }
         // etc...
    } 
}
```